# Calling a function within ThisDocument in Microsoft Word (VB.Net/VBA)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vba, ms-word

I have a VB.NET program that adds code to the ThisDocument module in MS Word in the following way:

```
wrdDoc.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisDocument").CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode)
```

Which creates the following sub:

```
Public Sub Example_Click()
Msgbox "Working" 
End Sub
```

I used to call this via the click event of a command button however it would be desirable call it from a ribbon button created as part of a COM Add-In.

I have been able to call global macros successfully in the Add-In by adding the following code to the button's click sub,.

```
Globals.TestWordApp.Application.Run("Macro1")
```

All attempts to run code contained within ThisDocument have failed however.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Subs in ThisDocument can be accessed as COM methods, but since they aren't in the typelib, in a COM environment you wuld typically have to get the dispid for the method via IDispatch and use that to call the method. AFAICS from a VB.NET VSTO addin you can in fact use      Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Macro1() to call such a macro, but it may not be the approved way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Run` runs macros.

Macros exist in modules, and `ThisDocument` is a class module.

Try creating a new module or use an existing module instead of `ThisDocument`.